# Reduction to a max flow problem from a sudoku like puzzle

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, network-flow

Given an $n$ by $n$ grid of which some of the squares are black and some are white. I'm allowed to mark some of these squares and the question is to prove whether a given grid with given black squares can meet these conditions:

1) Each column has only one marked square.

2) Each row has only one marked square.

3) Only white squares can be marked.

This is similar to how sudoku can only have the same number on only one column and one row. In fact it's an easier problem. However...

I am struggling to figure out an algorithm that reduces this problem to a max flow network problem.

I'm thinking something along the lines of making each square in the grid a  node in a graph. Then connect your source point to all the white nodes.

I also believe that in the end the way you prove whether such conditions can be met is by whether or not the max flow through this graph is exactly $n$. Because a solution to the above problem requires that there are exactly $n$ marked squares. Any less means that there was a row or column that doesn't have any white square or that there is no way of adding points that end up in distinct rows/columns.

Comment: Not sure that I understand your question, but if I do: Every 'valid partial filling' can be extended to a 'valid filling': The problem can be abstracted by putting numbered balls $1, \ldots, n$ in numbered urns $1, \ldots, n$ such that every urn contains exactly one ball. (Think of the $i$-th ball in the $j$-th urn as marking the $i$-th column of the $j$-th row.)

Comment: I found a website that pretty much has the problem (with a picture). http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/notes/24-maxflowapps.pdf
It's on page 9 problem 8. 
Also how can we make sure that if the some ith ball and some other ith+1 ball isn't on the same j column.

Comment: I see. I thought 'marking' a square meant 'painting it black'.

Comment: This question deserves more upvotes.  User has posted an interesting problem, shown his work, and been responsive to inquiries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have $n$ rows and $m$ columns.  Create $n$ nodes name $R_i$ to represent each row.

Each row can have at most 1 white square, so add 1 edge entering $R_i$ with a capacity of $1$.

If Table entry $T_{i,j}$ is white, add it to the graph.  Connect an edge from $R_i$ to $T_{i,j}$ with a capacity $1$.  This represents "The row has chosen this cell".

Now we need to represent "and no column is chosen more than once".  So add $m$ nodes $C_j$ to the graph to represent the columns.  Connect any existing $T_{i, j}$ to $C_j$ and give the column an input equal to how many cells are marked.

Each row can only have 1 marked cell, so add 1 edge to the output of $R_i$ and give it a capacity of $1$ so that it cannot input more than 1 cell.

Add a start node $S$ to feed the rows, and an end node $E$ to absorb the columns.  In summary:

$$\text{Vertices} = \{S, R_1, R_2, \dots R_n, T_{1, 1}, \dots \text{For those  cells that are white} \dots T_{n, m}, C_1, C_2, \dots C_m, E\}$$

And the directed edges $(\text{From}, \text{To}, \text{Capacity})$ are

$$\begin{array} {c}
(S, R_1, 1), (S, R_2, 1), \dots, (S, R_n, 1)\\
\\
(R_1, T_{1,1}, 1), (R_1, T_{1, 2}, 1), \dots, (R_1, T_{1, m}) \\
(R_2, T_{2,1}, 1), (R_2, T_{2, 2}, 1), \dots, (R_2, T_{2, m}) \\
\vdots \\
(R_n, T_{n,1}, 1), (R_n, T_{n, 2}, 1), \dots, (R_n, T_{n, m}) \\
\\
(T_{1,1}, C_1, 1), (T_{2,1}, C_1, 1), \dots, (T_{n, 1}, C_1, 1) \\
(T_{1,2}, C_2, 1), (T_{2,2}, C_2, 1), \dots, (T_{n, 2}, C_2, 1) \\\
\vdots \\
(T_{1,m}, C_m, 1), (T_{2,m}, C_m, 1), \dots, (T_{n, m}, C_m, 1) \\
\\
(C_1, E, 1), (C_2, E, 1), \dots, (C_m, E, 1)
\end{array}$$

Comment: oh my goodness. This is amazing... it's so beautiful! Did you just come up with this?? I've been thinking about this question for hours!!
What an elegant solution.

Comment: Yeah, first time I've seen the problem.

Comment: I'm so sad man. This problem seemed so cool, simple and I couldn't do it! Thanks for the answer! I marked yours as correct, but I cant upvote it since my reputation is garbage in this site.
If I may ask, what was your thought process?

Comment: I just tried to line up the concept of "max" (and my first 2 attempts didn't actually work).  Ford fulkerson maximizes flow.  You want to maximize the number of marked squares, but with an upper bound.  The hard part is figuring out how to encode the upper bound into the graph, so I just did it 1 step at a time, rows -> cells, then figured out that columns had to come after.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you very much for your time!
Hope you enjoyed solving this question a bit :)

Comment: Ford Fulkerson is an amazing seemingly unique case of an exponential definition with a polytime algorithm.  I love seeing an application of it.

Comment: I enjoyed learning this algorithm in class too. Actually this was the first algorithm that I learned such that with specific changes in implementation you can get a variable running time, e.g O(V E f*) where f* is the max flow, while at the same time being able to have a stable O(V E^2) if you change how you find your residual path. The professor also taught us how it was only declassified in the 80s-90s since it was developed during the cold war as a means to figure out the best way to knock out the russian railways.