# Is there a more abstract definition of a Sudoku Board

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, sudoku

I was trying to figure out why a Sudoku board needs 17 answers at least to be defined and I was wondering if there are already ways in which you could convert a Sudoku board into a group or graph and use graph or graph color theory to prove theorems about Sudoku. If you know of such or this doesn't belong here, let me know.

Comment: What about [this](https://pdxscholar.library.pdx.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1078&context=studentsymposium) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3093831/4x4-chromatic-sudoku-graph) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1648561/reduction-to-a-max-flow-problem-from-a-sudoku-like-puzzle/1648590#1648590)?

Comment: [Sudoku Squares and Chromatic Polynomials](https://www.ams.org/notices/200706/tx070600708p.pdf)

Comment: The minimum of $17$ was basically found by brute force. As far as I know, the minimum is unknown for larger sudokus.